# How to get any (x,y) point from smoothed kernel estimate function in R?

Tags: r

I have a scatter plot and I used ksmooth function to get smoothed line.
Now I want to get the residuals by subtracting real value from the one from smoothed line.
Maybe someone know how to find value of y for any x? Or maybe there's another way to get residuals?

```
plot(x,y)
kernel <- ksmooth(x,y, kernel="normal", bandwidth=0.01)
lines(kernel, col=2)
```

[Here is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpna9.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the fitted values directly from the model object returned by `ksmooth`. Here is a MWE:

```
x <- 1:100
y <- rnorm(100, mean=(x/2000)^2)
plot(x,y)
kernel <- ksmooth(x,y, kernel="normal", bandwidth=10, x.points=x)
lines(kernel, col=2)
resid <- kernel$y - y
print(resid)
```

Then run

```
all.equal(kernel$x, x)
```

Comment: This works but I'm not sure if it gives correct answer because x values and values of kernel$x are not the same, so I don't get residuals of the same x.

Comment: Really? When I try ``kernel$x==x`` I get a vector of true values.

Comment: I get different values, not sure where's the problem :/

Comment: @Engi; are you sure they are different. Try `all.equal(kernel$x, x)`

Comment: yep, i'm pretty sure they are different :D Where do you want me to use that all.eaqual() function? If I use it after applyng ksmooth() then it do not help because values of kernel$y just stay the same.

Comment: Can you post a minimal working example? The ``x`` output of ksmooth will be identical to your ``x`` variable. I've added the ``all.equal`` command to the answer in the relevant position.

Comment: This is how `kernel$x` and `x` look like > kernel$x
  [1] 0.1539161 0.1545246... and > x
  [1] 0.1678261 0.1663975...Obviously not the same. kernel$x==x just returns vector of FALSE because values do not match and all.equal(kernel$x, x) do not do any influence to residuals

Comment: Interesting, it seems that ``ksmooth`` does not evaluate the function at the x-values. From the info page: "x.points points at which to evaluate the smoothed fit. If missing, n.points are chosen uniformly to cover range.x." Therefore, you must specify the ``x.points`` argument to the function as well, which also takes your ``x`` variable as an input. I've added the correct code to the answer - hope this solves it!

Comment: Sadly, but no... i guess it's some kind of workspace problem, because i tried ksmooth() function with another data frame and kernel$x gave me back 100 values despite the fact, that x in original data had only 24 values

Comment: Did you try adding ``x.points=x`` to the function? This solves that problem for me

Comment: No idea then, I'm afraid.

Comment: i think I understood the problem. Values are the same but not in the same order. Probably that could happen beause i used yearmon() function to order them by month.

Comment: Great. If the answer has helped, it would be great to have it accepted. Cheers.

Comment: Note that this will not evaluate any points in `x.points`  that are outside the range of the data `x`.  So, if you called `kernel <- ksmooth(x,y, kernel="normal", bandwidth=10, x.points=c(130))`, it will give `NaN` for `kernel$y`.